# Where is the xUnit.net help file?

Tags: xunit.net

On the xUnit.net web site, they mention a [.CHM help file](http://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HowToViewHelp). Where can I find this file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the current releases do not incorporate the CHM file into the releases, either in [the downloads](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/releases) or the NuGet packages. Older releases on [the 1.x stream on CodePlex](https://xunit.codeplex.com/releases/) used to include it as a separate download, but 1.9.2 does not.

Best to clone it and build if you are interested (or if you believe more than just you want it on a regular basis, I'm sure a PR to make packaging and/or uploading it part of a normal build would likely be accepted - [just raise an Issue](http://xunit.github.io/) to verify the authors agree first)

It's also worth being aware of the doc site: http://xunit.github.io/